# Вывод изображения в WPF с сохранением пропорций

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Я вывожу картинку в xaml следующим образом:

```
<Ellipse Height="200"
         Width="200"
         Stroke="Black"
         StrokeThickness="1">
         <Ellipse.Fill>
             <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}" />
         </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Проблема в том что на выходе изображение выглядит следующим образом:

[image: вывод]

**Оригинал изображение выглядит так:**

[image: оригинал]

Каким образом я могу выводить изображение в кругу размером 200 на 200 пикселей, что бы изображение не растягивалось на всю область, а отображалось с соблюдением пропорций.

Comment: Свойство [Stretch](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.tilebrush.stretch?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Media_TileBrush_Stretch)

Comment: @ヒミコ я пробовал его установить со всеми возможными 4-я вариантами, однако изображение все время как было растянуто, так и остается

Comment: Куда вы его устанавливали? Вот вам пример, при `UniformToFill`, и без него. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z06D.png

Comment: @ヒミコ попробовал в Ellipse, потом в ImageBrush, потом одновременно и туда и туда. При любом варианте изображение искажено

Comment: Вам нужно установить только на кисть.

Comment: @ヒミコ прошу прощения, я тормоз. Не на той вкладке xaml устанавливал данное свойство. Все работает, спасибо